# How to show that $\sigma^2\psi_L^*$ transforms as a right-handed spinor? (Peskin&Schroeder)

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, spinors

In Peskin & Schroeder, it is written that the quantity $\sigma^2\psi_L^*$ transforms as a right-handed spinor. What confuses me is that I only get the correct result when considering the following:
\begin{equation}
\psi_L^*\to(\psi_L')^*=\exp\left((i\boldsymbol{\theta}-\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma^*}}{2}\right)\psi_L^*,
\end{equation}
from which the desired result follows by multiplying with $\sigma^2$ and using $\sigma^2\boldsymbol{\sigma}^*=-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\sigma^2$. However, to me, this looks like we considered the transformation of the spinor $\psi_L$ and not the transformation of the quantity $\sigma^2\psi_L^*$, where I understand the transformation of the latter as:
\begin{equation}
\sigma^2\psi_L^*\to(\sigma^2\psi_L^*)'=\exp\left((-i\boldsymbol{\theta}-\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}{2}\right)\sigma^2\psi_L^*=\sigma^2\exp\left((i\boldsymbol{\theta}+\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma}^*}{2}\right)\psi_L^*=\sigma^2(\psi_L')^*,
\end{equation}
which does look odd to me. What I expect when reading "show that $\sigma^2\psi_L^*$ transforms as a right-handed spinor" is something along the line of:
\begin{equation}
\sigma^2\psi_L^*\to(\sigma^2\psi_L^*)'=S[\Lambda]\sigma^2\psi_L^*,
\end{equation}
which is not what I get when doing the calculations, as shown above.

I hope that I made it clear what confuses me.

Comment: Your second equation is correct. It is just a definition of what $(\sigma^2 \psi_L^*)'$ is

Comment: @nwolijin Yes, but it isn't the desired transformation as shown in my third equation, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left handed spinors $\psi_{\text{L}}$ transform as
$$
\psi_{\text{L}} \mapsto \exp\left((-\mathrm{i}\boldsymbol{\theta} +\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}{2} \right)\psi_{\text{L}}\tag{1}
$$
and right handed spinors $\psi_{\text{R}}$ transform as
$$
\psi_{\text{R}} \mapsto \exp\left((-\mathrm{i}\boldsymbol{\theta} -\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}{2} \right)\psi_{\text{R}}. \tag{2}
$$
Using equation (1), the object $\sigma_2\psi_{\text{L}}^*$ transforms as
\begin{align}
\sigma_2\psi_{\text{L}}^* \quad\mapsto & \quad\sigma_2\left[\exp\left((-\mathrm{i}\boldsymbol{\theta} +\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}{2} \right)\psi_{\text{L}}\right]^* \\
&= \sigma_2\exp\left((\mathrm{i}\boldsymbol{\theta} +\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma}^*}{2} \right)\psi_{\text{L}}^* \\
&= \sigma_2\exp\left((\mathrm{i}\boldsymbol{\theta} +\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{-\sigma_2\boldsymbol{\sigma}\sigma_2}{2} \right)\psi_{\text{L}}^*\\
&= \underbrace{\sigma_2^2}_{1}\exp\left(-(\mathrm{i}\boldsymbol{\theta} +\boldsymbol{\beta})\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}{2} \right)\sigma_2\psi_{\text{L}}^*,
\end{align}
that is, in the same way as the right handed spinor in equation (2).

Comment: Just to be sure: In the third line, you used $\sigma_2\boldsymbol{\sigma}^*=-\boldsymbol{\sigma}\sigma_2\Rightarrow\boldsymbol{\sigma}^*=-\sigma_2\boldsymbol{\sigma}\sigma_2$ since $\sigma_2$ is its own inverse, right?

Comment: Yep exactly! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I never thought about using this relation in that way. ^^

Comment: I have another question regarding your computations: In your first line, you essentially move $\sigma^2$ past the transformation matrix, allowing you to consider the transformation of $\psi_L$. In other words, why is it allowed to first consider the transformation of $\psi_L^*$ to then multiply with $\sigma^2$ afterwards? Shouldn't we consider what $\sigma^2$ does to $\psi_L$ before transforming? So, in a sense, the transformation $S[\Lambda]$ should commute with $\sigma^2$, correct? But how do we show this?

Comment: That is the essence of the error that you made in your calculation: $\sigma_2$ does not transform, it is just a matrix! To find the transformation of the object $\sigma_2\psi_{\text{L}}^*$ you have to apply the known transformation law of $\psi_{\text{L}}$. You *derive* the transformation of $\sigma_2\psi_{\text{L}}^*$ from that of $\psi_{\text{L}}$; you cannot simply assume that $\sigma_2\psi_{\text{L}}^*$ will transform in the same way as $\psi_{\text{L}}$.

Comment: I think this is where my confusion about the different representations sets in. Can you elaborate on why $\sigma^2$ doesn't transform, and what you mean by "it is just a matrix"? I looked at it this way: $S[\Lambda]$ carries spinor indices, and so does $\sigma^2$ since it acts on a spinor. So I thought, and I apparently still think, that $S[\Lambda]$ affects $\sigma^2$ in some way. I might be overthinking this too much, but I am just trying to understand this better. :)

Comment: Suppose you have a contravariant four vector $A^\mu$, and that you multiply it by the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ to obtain $A_\nu = \eta_{\mu\nu}A^\mu$. The object $A_\nu$ of course transforms as a covariant four vector. The reason this is possible is that $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is an *invariant tensor* of the vector representation of the Lorentz group: it obeys $\Lambda{^\mu}_\rho\Lambda{^\nu}_\sigma \eta_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\rho\sigma}$, so is unaffected by a transformation. Note that it is incorrect to say that $\eta$ transforms under the Lorentz group - it is just a matrix.

Comment: The relation of $\sigma_2$ to $\psi_{\text{L}}$ is directly analogous: $\sigma_2$ is an invariant tensor of the left-handed spinor representation of the Lorentz group: $(S_{\text{L}}){_a}^c (S_{\text{L}}){_b}^d (\sigma_2)_{cd} = (\sigma_2)_{ab}$ ($a, b, c, d = 1,2$ are spinor indices in Van-der Waerden notation). This means that it is possible to multiply a left-handed spinor by $\sigma_2$ in a Lorentz covariant way, and importantly the form of $\sigma_2$ is the same independent of the reference frame used.

Comment: As a side note, if you read about the invariant tensors of the Lorentz group you might see talk of the invariant tensor $\epsilon_{ab} = -\epsilon_{ba}$. This is directly proportional to $\sigma_2$.